# Charts with date as x-axis using react-native-svg-charts

Tags: javascript, react-native, charts, react-native-svg-charts

I have a dataset

```
2019/1/1 - 14
2019/1/5 - 18
2019/2/19 - 17
2019/3/15 - 18
```

that I want to show in a line diagram in my React Native app. I use react-native-svg-charts for my charts, and while I'd prefer using that I'm of course willing to look at alternatives.

How can I make a line-graph that has the values 14-18 on the y-axis and the dates distributed on the x-axis so that the graph shows the non-regularity in the data entries? Until now I get them so that each entry is equally spaced to its neighbour, and I want the spacing between the entries to reflect the distance in time between the entries.